# What is the purpose of listener in WebSphere MQ?

Tags: jms, listener, ibm-mq

When I go to my WebSphere MQ explorer, and connect to a remote queue manager and go to `--> Advanced --> Listeners`, I do not see any listeners defined. But I am able to create a remote JMS client, connect to this queue manager by using a channel connection  and publish a message to a topic.

So what is the purpose of listeners? In my case, things are working fine without listeners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebSphere MQ listeners are what accepts remote connections and start inbound channels. Modern queue managers will almost always have listeners defined but it is also possible to specify a default port for the QMgr to listen on without actually defining a listener.  This is unusual, though.  For older versions of MQ it was common to use `inetd` to start channels.  This method doesn't use a listener.

So rest assured that *something* on your QMgr is listening for connections.  Since you are not seeing it there are three likely possibilities:

- The listener name starts with `SYSTEM.` and your Explorer view is set to filter SYSTEM objects.
- The default port has been specified in the `qm.ini` file
- You have a really old QMgr using `inetd`

By the way, go get a new version of WMQ Explorer.  Since you have an `Advanced --> Listeners` you must have an old version.  Download from [SupportPac MS0T](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0T).